# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: entity USING HTTPPOST METHODE

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Hello when i use Post methode using Web API i was not able to add it to database.
I used Jquery to call api POST METHODE
While using postman i was able to post some data to database.
I guess the problem in the view or in the Jquery. Any help please

MVC CONTROLLER

```
        public ActionResult New(Customers customers)
    {
       
        return View(customers);
    }
```

API CONTROLLER FOR POST

```
        [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult CreateCustomer(Customers CustomerDTO)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
      
        _context.Customerss.Add(CustomerDTO);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return Created(new Uri(Request.RequestUri + "/" + CustomerDTO.Id), CustomerDTO);

    }
```

VIEW

```
    @model API.Models.Customers


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "New";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>New Form</h2>

<div id="container">
    <form>
        <div class="form-group" id="NameGroup">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-control", id = "Name" })
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary js-Add">Save</button>
    </form>
</div>


@section scripts {

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            
            $("#container .js-Add").on("click", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                if (confirm("Are you sure you want to ADD this customer?")) {

                    var input = $("Name").val();

                    $.ajax({
                        url: "../api/Customer",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: JSON.stringify(input),
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (response) {
                            alert('HELLO' + response.Name);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

CLASS CUSTOMER

```
    public class Customers
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

ANY HELP PLEASE OR ANY ADVISE
THANK YOU!!

Comment: If your just trying to pass the customer name and not an actual object, just change the accepted parameter for your API POST method.
Try this instead:   
$.ajax({
        url: "../api/Customer",
        data: {
            'custName': input
        },
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json'
    })


Change your API POST method to this:
     [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult CreateCustomer(string custName) { .... }

Comment: hi Filipe thank you for your help, i want to post the name of the customer to my database using post methode. is it worng to call the api this way using jquery or is another way to call or use the HttpPost to post data to database

Comment: Because your MVC app is separate from your API (or this is what it seems like at least), you could also have jquery call a post  method on your MVC controller first, which then uses httpclient to call the API. But the way you currently have it is not wrong. Did you try doing what I mentioned on my first comment?